# How to make pywinauto faster (keyboard.send_keys)?

Tags: python, variables, pywinauto

```
pwa.keyboard.send_keys ("StackOverflow")
```

with this code, the text is printed 1 letter at a time **(long)**

how to make it so that the text is entered completely at once? (works with **1000+ variables**)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to change the optional parameter pause to zero like this:

```
pwa.keyboard.SendKeys("StackOverflow", pause=0)
```

There are more details on this [here](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/493)